# Looping over columns to standardize those that are numeric

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

Using R I am trying to loop over all columns in my dataset and standardize those columns that are numeric using a for loop, an if statement, and the scale function.

Currently my code to do so looks as follows:

```
for (columns in names(data)){
   if class(data[[columns]]) == "numeric"{
      data$columns = scale(data$columns)
   }
   print(columns)
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Do you need a for loop and if statement or are you open to other approaches, e.g. from the tidyverse?

Comment: Please also share an example of your data.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data("iris")
#Code
new <- iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric),~scale(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find numeric columns and apply `scale` to it. For example, with built-in `iris` dataset.

```
cols <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
iris[cols] <- scale(iris[cols])
iris

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1        -0.8977      1.0156      -1.3358   -1.311052     setosa
#2        -1.1392     -0.1315      -1.3358   -1.311052     setosa
#3        -1.3807      0.3273      -1.3924   -1.311052     setosa
#4        -1.5015      0.0979      -1.2791   -1.311052     setosa
#5        -1.0184      1.2450      -1.3358   -1.311052     setosa
#6        -0.5354      1.9333      -1.1658   -1.048667     setosa
#...
#...
```